# How to change a textbox removing extra symbols and spaces

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Currently i use this code:

```
 private static void ArrayFixer(TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Trim();
        while (tb.Text.Contains("  ")) tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace("  ", " ");
        while (tb.Text.Contains("- ")) tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace("- ", "-");
        while (tb.Text.Contains("--")) tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace("--", "-");
    }
```

This works fine, but if input is `5-   4  -3-  -4` result will be `5-4 -3-4` 
and i want it be something like `5 4 -3 -4`

Im stacked on this line (it looks terribly wrong)

```
while (tb.Text.Contains(Convert.ToString(char.IsDigit(???) + "-")) //replace ("-"," ")
```

I mean the textbox becomes almost as i want: numbers are separated by `" "` that's pretty much it. And i need to avoid `5-` or `3-` in my string.

Comment: Can you try and explain the logic you try to achieve?

Comment: From `5-   4  -3-  -4` shouldn't you be expecting `5 -4 -3 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looking for something like this? It will extract valid integers from input string.

```
var str = "5-   4  -3-  -4";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "-?[0-9]+");
var res = string.Join(" ", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
```

**Update**

To exclude cases mentioned in comment you can use this regex

```
(?<=\s|^)-?[1-9]\d+
```

**Update 2**

This pattern will match all positive and negative integers at the start of word like `123someword` => `123` or `-1otherword` => `-1` as well as same with trailing zeros like `000234word` => 234 (only positives).

```
(?<=^|\s|\s0*)-?[1-9]\d*
```

Comment: Little problem : numbers like '00000000000005' or '-007' can be added into string also. Any way to fix in using this Regex methods?

Comment: 1 error: `Unrecognized escape sequence`. I fixed it as follows: `"(?<=\\s|^)-?[1-9]\\d+"` or `@"(?<=\s|^)-?[1-9]\d+"` but now it works as follows: single numbers `1` `2` are deleted, numbers like `005` `-00007` are deleted, numbers like `12` `46` `123` `443` and more are stored.

Comment: Almost perfect!! But now I'm not able to store single `0` into the textbox

Comment: Add this at the end of regex `|(?<=\s)0(?=\s)`.

Comment: Still almost. `0` is stored if i put it between any 2 numbers like `1 0 2`, if i put it as a last item like `5 4 3 2 1 0` it's gone. if u put `0 0 1` result is `0 1`
Regex is `@"(?<=^|\s|\s0*)-?[1-9]\d*|(?<=\s)0(?=\s)"`

Comment: Enjoy `(?<=^|\s|\s0*)-?[1-9]\d*|(?<=^|\s)0(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect! I won't forget your kindness.